# Writing clojure maps/arrays to a file and reading them back

Tags: file-io, clojure

I need to save clojure maps to a file and read them back later to process them.

This is what I could come up with. Is there a better way to accomplish the same thing?

```
user=> (def my-data (for [ a [ "Person1" "Person2" ]  b [ "Address1" "Address2"]  c   (range 10) ] {:name a :address b :index c} ))
#'user/my-data
user=> (count my-data)
40

user=> (defn write-data[xs] (with-open [wrtr (clojure.java.io/writer "my-data.txt") ]
              (doall (map #(.write wrtr (str % "\n")) xs))))
#'user/write-data

user=> (write-data my-data)

user=> (defn read-data[] (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "my-data.txt") ]
            (doall (map #(load-string %) (line-seq rdr)))))
#'user/read-data

user=> (count (read-data))
40
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is easiest to read a single form to and from the file, so I usually put my data into a vector. 
I also prefer to use pr or `pr-str` rather than print because it is guaranteed to produce readable data,

```
(def my-data [{:a "foo" :b [1 2 3]} "asdf" 42 #{1 2 3}]) 
(spit "/tmp/data.edn" (with-out-str (pr my-data)))
nil
(read-string (slurp "/tmp/data.edn"))
[{:a "foo", :b [1 2 3]} "asdf" 42 #{1 2 3}]
```

vs:

```
(spit "/tmp/data.edn" (with-out-str (print my-data)))
(read-string (slurp "/tmp/data.edn"))
[{:a foo, :b [1 2 3]} asdf 42 #{1 2 3}]
```

notice how the string `"asdf" was read back as a symbol.

`.toString` also works fine:

```
(spit "/tmp/data.edn" (.toString my-data)) 
(read-string (slurp "/tmp/data.edn"))
[{:a "foo", :b [1 2 3]} "asdf" 42 #{1 2 3}]
```

Comment: There's already a function `clojure.core/pr-str` that does `(with-out-str (pr x))`.

Answer (score 16):

Yes - `spit` and `prn-str` for writing, `slurp` and `read-string` for reading.

```
user=> (def a [1 2 3 4])
#'user/a
user=> (prn-str a)
"[1 2 3 4]\n"
user=> (spit "stored-array.dat" (prn-str a))
nil
```

(in a new REPL session)

```
user=> (require 'clojure.edn)
nil
user=> (slurp "stored-array.dat")
"[1 2 3 4]\n"
user=> (clojure.edn/read-string (slurp "stored-array.dat"))
[1 2 3 4]
```

I used a vector for that example, but any data (e.g. maps) should work just as well.

Note that there is a read-string in the main Clojure language, but this is explicitly documented as not being safe for untrusted data, so it's better to use the version from clojure.edn.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946979/how-i-can-deserialize-record-structure-from-file-already-saved-to-file-with-pri) that deals with `print-dup` and serializing forms. It has a better coverage of the trade-offs and security issues involved with each method.