# code as data: update a clojure file programmatically

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Say you are using leiningen and you want to add a dependency to your project.clj file.

Instead of opening your editor and add this manually it must be possible to do so programmatically via the clojure language. Like so:

```
(update-in :dependencies conj ["enlive" "1.1.3"])
```

lein's update-in is not helping, since it does not make the change for good.

How would you guys do this?

Comment: Did my reply help you in the end?

Answer (score 2):

Since `project.clj` is a Clojure file, you could put this at the top of your `project.clj` file :

```
(def my-deps [["enlive" "1.1.3"]])
```

..and later on :

```
 :dependencies my-deps
```

Which means that you could even `slurp` an `.edn` file that you could edit however you want. I actually have this on the top of my `build.boot` (equivalent of `project.clj` but for `boot`) :

```
(defn slurp-deps []
  (read-string (slurp "resources/deps.edn")))
```

And I use it like so :

```
:dependencies (slurp-deps)
```

The rest would just be updating your map and [writing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19147717/1327651) it back to the same `.edn` file.

If you want to reload your dependencies after that have a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16409182/1327651).

Note : as an alternative, I know that this is the way to do things in a REPL with [`boot`](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot), and that it will fetch/load the dependencies :

```
boot.user=> (set-env! 
       #_=>   :resource-paths #{"src"}
       #_=>   :dependencies '[["enlive" "1.1.3"]])
```